# Is this use of unions in C valid/compliant?

Tags: c, struct, unions

Given these structures:

```c
typedef struct {
    //[...]
} StructA;

typedef struct {
    StructA a;
    //[...]
} StructB;

typedef union {
    StructA a;
    StructB b;
} Union;
```

Are the two access methods below equivalent and not undefined?

```c
Union u;
memcpy(&u.b, /*...*/); //Pretend I populated StructB here
u.a;    // Method 1
u.b.a;  // Method 2
```

Note that StructA happens to be the first member of StructB.

I spotted this in a codebase that works, I'm just wondering if it is standard or if there are any alignment gotchas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef union {
    StructA a;
    StructB b;
} Union;
```

`a` has the same offset as `b` in the union: 0

`a` has offset 0 in `StructB`.

The calls are equivalent.